# Problem in padding and positioning in a simple html template

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me how to make text in the boxes can be pushed down to stop overlapping and text shouldn't go out of the box? Also, I need some margin in the column boxes.

**There are media queries and ignore that one. I just want to know how to change the CSS so that text is not overflowing from the box and I don't want to use the overflow property also. Also how to give the margin to the column boxes provided boxes remain in the line.**

Code CSS and HTML -->

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

div.row div {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: relative;

}

.heading{
    margin: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}

/*For large devices*/
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .col-lg-3{
        float : left;
        width: 33.33%;
    }
}
/*For medium devices*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .col-md-2{
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-12{
        float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
/*For small devices*/
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .col-sm-12{
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
h2.item1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2%;
}
h2.item2 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2%;
}
h2.item3 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: skyblue;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2%;
}

section {
    padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Our Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item1">Chicken</h2>
        <section class="desc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui zfiofficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item2">Beef</h2>
        <section class="desc2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item3">Sushi</h2>
        <section class="desc3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add padding from top like this **div.row div{padding-top: 50px;}**

Answer (score 1):

By setting the `position` to `absolute` you are removing the `html` from the normal *'flow'* of the document, so you can't apply normal css properties such as `margin`.

To circumvent this, you should `float` the `h2`'s `right` instead and then apply a margin to prevent your text being hiddent under the element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

div.row div {
    background-color: gray;
    border: 1px black solid;
    position: relative;

}

.heading{
    margin: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    text-align:center;
}

/*For large devices*/
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .col-lg-3{
        float : left;
        width: 33.33%;
    }
}
/*For medium devices*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){
    .col-md-2{
        float:left;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-md-12{
        float: left;
    width: 100%;
    }
}
/*For small devices*/
@media (max-width: 767px){
    .col-sm-12{
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
h2.item1, h2.item2, h2.item3 {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: .3rem;
}
h2.item2 {
    background-color: green;
}
h2.item3 {
    background-color: skyblue;
}

section {
    padding: 2%;
}

.desc1, .desc2, .desc3{
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Our Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">Our Menu</h1>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item1">Chicken</h2>
        <section class="desc1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui zfiofficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item2">Beef</h2>
        <section class="desc2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
        <h2 class="item3">Sushi</h2>
        <section class="desc3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```